# How to insert multiple record of JSON that stored in an Array using mysql and knex js (Node js)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I have a code to store id_company, id_variablepoint, and answer to table "answer" using knex js (node js) and mysql

```
router.post("/insert_answer", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id_company = req.body.id_company;
  const id_variablepoint = req.body.id_variablepoint;
  const answer = req.body.answer;

  try{
    const tambah = await knex("answer").insert([{id_company:id_company, id_variablepoint:id_variablepoint, answer:answer}])
    res.json({
      "data":tambah
    })
  }catch(e){
    const error = new Error ("ERROR: "+e);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

and I have a problem to store request that look like this because it's stored in array

```
[
    {
        "id_company":2,
        "id_variablepoint":57,
        "answer":"choose"
    },
    {
        "id_company":2,
        "id_variablepoint":49,
        "answer":"choose"
    }
]
```

My database structure looks like this:

[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yucJn.png)

please help me, thank you

Comment: so. what is the problem exactly?  Request is an array?

Answer (score 0):

According to knex [doc](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert) knex 'insert' support arrays. so you don't need to worry in your scenario. just pass the request into knex insert.

`const tambah = await knex("answer").insert(req.body);`